# how to select the following data from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

Okay so I have two tables as, one table has only two columns (meetid,userid(foregin key)) and the second table has (userid,name,address,covidresults). I need to get probable cases who have met with someone(have same meet id) with covidresults '+ve'.

lets say that userid 1 has covid, and he has 3 meetings with (user 2,user 3),(user 2),(user 4,user 5)
it would be stored as
(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(2,1)(2,2)(3,1)(3,4),(3,5)
....
I have tried this

```
select m.userid from meetinguser m,user n group by m.meetid where m.userid=n.userid and n.CovidStatus='+ve'
```

It doesnt work. Any help would be highly appreciated
I am doing this on python Mysql connector and i tried first getting list of all meetings 1 has been in and getting data from meeting Id

```
mycur.executemany("select userid from meetinguser where meetid='%s'",meetingsofuser)
```

where meetingsofuser=[1,2,4]

Comment: this gives me a long error

Comment: First you're missing the join condition and where comes before group by

Comment: Umm I have solved this problem using python loops. How to close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I have an answer to this question. If it helps, I fetched the meetids first for those who have covid then I fetched data for userids multiple times using loops and append to a list then I removed sure cases then I got probable cases. (I am posting this solution to close the question:/)